# "SystemFolder" in WIX and C#

Tags: c#, path, installation, wix, system32

An installer I have created with WiX installs a DLL using the `SystemFolder` variable, as well as a C# app into another folder. I want to directly reference the DLL from the app. Do I need to look up registry keys to find where the `SystemFolder` is?

Answer (score 16):

No, you don't need to query the registry. Windows Installer has a series of built-in properties that automatically resolve to special well known locations such as SystemFolder.

See [System Folder Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system_folder_properties) for more general information.  For WiX, just create a Directory element as a direct child of the TARGETDIR Directory element:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="SystemFolder" Name="SystemFolder" />
</Directory>
```

If you already know this and want to know how to reference the DLL from C#, SystemFolder is in the search path so I'm not sure why you'd have to.   If it was me, I'd compile the C# as x86 ( AnyCPU is somewhat out of vogue now ) and use:

```
string myDllPath = Path.Combine( System.Environment.SystemDirectory, "my.dll" );
```